# Project a time range in multiple rows with Postgres

Tags: postgresql

I have some rows like this:

```
 avg_income | date_from  | date_to
------------+------------+------------
     1256.9 | 2016-11-21 | 2017-07-10
     4383.2 | 2017-05-06 | 2017-06-01
```

and I would like to project the `avg_income` values to the respective months, like this:

```
 avg_income | month
------------+------------
     1256.9 | 2016-11-01 
     1256.9 | 2016-12-01 
     1256.9 | 2017-01-01 
     1256.9 | 2017-02-01 
     1256.9 | 2017-03-01 
     1256.9 | 2017-04-01 
     1256.9 | 2017-05-01 
     1256.9 | 2017-06-01 
     1256.9 | 2017-07-01 
     4383.2 | 2017-05-01 
     4383.2 | 2017-06-01
```

So far I just came out with an awful `FOR/LOOP/generate_series(...)` so I am wondering is there a more elegant (and efficient) way to do it?

Comment: What is awful about using `generate_series` to fill the gaps?

Comment: it is not about `generate_series` but the usage of the `FOR/LOOP` along with it. Also, my data are not just the `avg_income` but there are more complicated `join` in the middle that make the process slow.

Comment: You don't need a PL/pgSQL FOR loop to use `generate_series()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `generate_series()` for this.

```
select t.avg_income, d.month
from the_table t
  cross join lateral ( 
    select g.m::date as month
    from generate_series(date_trunc('month', t.date_from), date_trunc('month', t.date_to), interval '1 month') as g (m)
  ) as d
order by t.avg_income, d.month;
```

Alternatively:

```
select t.avg_income, d.month::date
from the_table t
  cross join lateral generate_series(date_trunc('month', t.date_from), date_trunc('month', t.date_to), interval '1 month') as d (month)
order by t.avg_income, d.month;
```

Online example: http://rextester.com/ADG4243

Comment: Deleting my (almost identical) answer. Feel free to use the fiddle. (the generate_series doesn't need to be in a subselect)

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ: I know that `generate_series()` could be used without the derived table, but I prefer to do the casting in the "source" not in the final select - but that's obviously personal taste.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ why did you delete your answer? It looked quite simple.

Comment: @Randomize because it's essentially the same as this one. Link to the [fiddle](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=6f7ce24ff458d5ffb5fae4580aab65bf) for those that can't see deleted answers.